# Is there a way about how to send a value from the Child component to the Parent component using EventEmitter but without using event binding?

Tags: angular, components, output, interaction, emitter

I have a parent component which is a form, but this form has different sections, so I created a Child component for each section of the form. So I need to send values from the child to the parent but I cannot use event binding because I am using (routing) routerLink to display each section, there is no way to pass it through event binding, because they are being displayed when we enter the right path.

Is there any alternative to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Hey a code sample showing the problem would be great. But you can also use services for communication between components.

Comment: Yes, I have read something about shared services. I was kind of avoiding to use it and looking for other alternatives. Perhaps I need to take a deeper look at that. Thanks :)

Comment: please add code to better understand your case

Answer (score 1):

By using services you can exchange values with observables. You basically have an observable and an observer. You inject your serivce via dependency Injection to the .ts files that communicate with eachother. You .next(value) in that .ts file where the value is coming from and then subscribe to it in the receiving .ts file. Once you understand that behaviour, observables make a lot of things easier for you when it comes to communication, plus you will need to learn it anyway when you make http-Requests. Here is a helpfull link:  https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3

Comment: Thanks for the answer and shared info. I will take a look at Observables. :)

Comment: No problem. If you have any more question according to observables feel free to ask. If I could help you I would really appreciate it if you could upvote my answer:)